# Cycles. Box on font line unable to delete

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a box on the font line of my text crawl that also appears to be a point of axis for the crawl. I cannot remove it without deleting the text. I am pretty new to blender so still learning, below is the link to my blend http://www.filedropper.com/attempt1_1 . can you look over it to see what I am doing wrong? [image]

Comment: It looks like a character the font does not have so it shows up as a block maybe. Check the source text in a text editor and make sure there are no strange characters.

Comment: enter edit mode and select and delete the square

Comment: Please use another service for sharing files without entering captcha; [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) is often used here. As for the square, letters are already converted into mesh, so enter Edit mode and delete unwanted vertices, as @Chebhou suggested.

Comment: hi, thanks I will use blend-exchange from now on. I will just redo the whole thing as when i enter edit mode click delete vertices nothing happens heh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you converted the text to a mesh(That's how it was when i downloaded the .blend), there was more than one, many in fact, squares overlapping it's self.

Just select all, press <kbd>W</kbd> and select *remove doubles*. Then, select the square again and delete it.

***A step by step guide:***

1. Select the text.
2. Enter *Edit mode*.
3. Select all and then press <kbd>W</kbd> then press *Remove doubles*.
4. Press <kbd>Z</kbd> to go into *Wireframe mode*.
5. Press <kbd>C</kbd> to turn on *Circle select*.
6. Select the square using *Circle select*.
7. Press <kbd>X</kbd> or *Delete* and then press *Vertices* .
8. Exit *Edit mode*, and it should be done. :)

[Link to the process.](https://i.imgur.com/MGZpFTq.gifv)

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments, I removed doubles, but it wont let me select the square independently and just dletes the whole text. I dont know how to go back in and change the text or convert back to text from mesh

Comment: @LucidDreams Added a step by step guide. :)

Comment: your a legend thank you for that! display means a lot ill play with that when i have time thankyou again. top answer

Comment: @LucidDreams No problem.